# Validating Date Format in a column having different date formats

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I have a text column in a table which can have date data in any of the possible date formats. I need to validate if the date specified in the column is a valid date format or not.
What I have done is, I have created another table which contains the Posix expressions of all possible date formats and then written an update query.

But I am struck on update query. Its is comparing particular date format with all the data in formats table and updating the output as "Not Valid Date" when compared with the other format.

Data Table : -

Id  C1          message
1   22-Nov-2019 
2   22-Nov-19
3   22/11/2019
4   22/11/19
5   11/22/19
6   11/22/2019

Formats Table: -

date_pattern    date_format
YYYY-MM-DD  ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))-(((0)[0-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))$
YYYY-DD-MM  ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-(((0)[0-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))-(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))$
YYYY/MM/DD  ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))/(((0)[0-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))$
YYYY/DD/MM  ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/(((0)[0-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))/(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))$
AA  ^(([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$

Update Query: -

update x_test set  message =    concat (message, ' Date Datatype not properly mentioned - col2; ')
from (select date_format formatt from brms.dates ) varformat   where not  ( c2 ~  varformat.formatt)

Comment: The database is not the best place to be doing this kind of cleanup work.  Is there any chance you could fix the data at its source?

Comment: We need to create data validations in the db for all the data that we receive from the client.

Comment: Then consider creating a stored procedure or UDF for this.